# Why shouldn't the value of an object be accessed using the following operators in address constant expressions?

Tags: c

I have been trying to undersand the following quote from C11 Standard

> **6.6  Constant expressions**
>
> ...
>
> 9. **An address constant** is a null pointer, a pointer to an lvalue designating an object of static
>    storage duration, or a pointer to a function designator; it shall be created explicitly using
>    the unary & operator or an integer constant cast to pointer type, or implicitly by the use of
>    an expression of array or function type. The array-subscript [] and member-access .
>    and -> operators, the address & and indirection * unary operators, and pointer casts may
>    be  used  in  the  creation  of  an  address  constant,  but  **the  value  of  an  object  shall  not  be
>    accessed by use of these operators.**

How are the values of an object  accessed by using those operators, although they shouldn't be?  Could you give some examples?

Why shouldn't the value of an object accessed by using those operators?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is saying that an expression forming an address constant is not allowed to depend on the value of an object.

This is analogous to a simpler case:

```
// at file scope
int x = 10;        // OK, 10 is an integer constant expression
int y = x;         // Error, x is the value of an object
```

For the address constant case, it is reminding us that the computation of the address constant should not read the value of an object in forming that computation, e.g.:

```
int a[5];                // OK
int *p = &a[1];          // OK
int *q = &a[1] + a[0];   // Error, uses value of a[0]
```

Comment: Thanks. Is `int y=x` an error because initializers to static or external objects must be constant expressions?

Comment: No, no, that was just an analogy to set up the explanation using `int a[5];` There is nothing wrong with `int x = 10, y = x;` the integers assign *values*.and not an *address constant* depending on anything in the computation.

Comment: @Tim Yes, that's correct (David is mistaken to say that there's nothing wrong with initializing `y` with `x`)

Answer (score 1):

This statement is best illustrated with a simple example:

```
static struct {
    int id;
    int count;
} items[20];

int *midCount = &items[10].count;
```

Above, `midCount` is an address constant pointing to `count` field of `items` struct at index ten. The address-of operator is applied to the result of member access and array subscript operators in order to obtain the address. However, `int` object at the said address is *not* accessed, in accordance with the specification.

Here is an expression that accesses the object at the same location as the address-of expression above:

```
int count = items[10].count;
```

> Why shouldn't the value of an object accessed by using those operators?

Because it is not required to compute the address constant. The compiler can compute the offset of `count` inside `items` array, and apply this offset during the loading, when `items` is bound to memory, without reading or writing the location itself. This is similar to the behavior of `sizeof` operator, which does not evaluate its expressions:

```
size_t sz = sizeof(items[10].count); // No memory access
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the restriction on accessing the value is not during runtime but during translation. One is not allowed to dereference a constant expression pointer in a constant expression.

For instance

```
// global scope
int a = 0;
int *b = (a++ , &a);
```

We do not want the compiler to keep track of the state of `a` while building the initial value of `b`.

Also the actual value at that address might not be known to the compiler because it might be defined in another translation unit with some constant initializer.

Comment: Changed the example from `&(a++)` because `++` returns an rvalue.